# Ambari- Import multiple files to Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, ambari

I have a python script that generates schemas, drop table and load table commands for files in a directory that I want to import into Hive. I can then run these in Ambari to import files. Multiple 'create table' commands can be executed, but when uploading files to import into their respective Hive tables, I can only upload one file at a time.

Is there a way to perhaps put these commands in a file and execute them all at once so that all tables are created and the relevant files are subsequently uploaded to their respective tables?

I have also tried importing files to HDFS with the aim of then sending them to Hive via Linux using 'hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/ixroot/Documents/ImportToHDFS  /hadoop/hdfs' commands, but errors such as 'no such directory' crop up with regards to 'hadoop/hdfs'. I have tried changing permissions using chmod, but these don't seem to be effective either.

I would be very grateful if anyone could tell me which route would be better to pursue with regards to efficiently importing multiple files into their respective tables in Hive.

Answer (score 0):

1) Is there a way to perhaps put these commands in a file and execute them all at once so that all tables are created and the relevant files are subsequently uploaded to their respective tables?

*You can give all the queries in a .hql file, something like test.hql and run `hive -f test.hql` to execute all command in one shot*

2) errors such as 'no such directory'

*give `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /hadoop/hdfs`* and then type `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/ixroot/Documents/ImportToHDFS /hadoop/hdfs`

Edit: for permission

hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/ixroot

Comment: Thanks Nirmal, I have tried that, but as with otherhive related commands I get the following error: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=ixroot, access=WRITE, inode="/user/ixroot":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x'

Comment: I have tried chmod commands, they do seem to change read/write properties when doing 'ls -al', but don't seem to have any effect on importing files.

Comment: I have tried 'sudo chmod 771 hdfs' ad the thing is that there IS a '/home/hdfs' directory, but whenever I try to access it or execute a chmod it says 'chmod: cannot access ‘hdfs’: No such file or directory'.

Comment: I can build Hive tables without sending to HDFS first, in my first method I go to user -> admin -> data, drop the files there using Ambari. Perhaps the HDFS step is not needed.

Comment: Thanks Nirmal, I do not have a user/ixroot directory, but I do have a user/hdfs directory, I tried 'hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hdfs', but it said 'chmod: changing permissions of '/user/hdfs': Permission denied. user=ixroot is not the owner of inode=hdfs'

Comment: i am confused here. can you say what command are you trying and the error faced

Comment: when did you get this error -> 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=ixroot, access=WRITE, inode="/user/ixroot":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x'

Comment: This command: ' hive -f  bulkImportCode.hql' gave the error: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=ixroot, access=WRITE, inode="/user/ixroot":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x' -> and this error was followed by many more 'check permission' lines.

Comment: the command ' hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hdfs' resulted in the error: 'chmod: changing permissions of '/user/hdfs': Permission denied. user=ixroot is not the owner of inode=hdfs'

Comment: ok for that type "hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/ixroot" then "hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/ixroot" and then try hive command

Comment: That doesn't work either,  'hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/ixroot' gives:
mkdir: Permission denied: user=ixroot, access=WRITE, inode="/user/ixroot":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

Comment: can you share your core site.xml

Comment: I tried to find that before, but did not know the directory in which it is situated, do you know where I could find it? Thanks again.

Comment: in hadoop conf path

Comment: or in /etc/group for group hdfs add ixroot

Comment: Sorry, but in the hadoop directory, the only two folders are hdfs and zookeeper, in zookeeper there is no core xml either.

Comment: are you using ambari ?

Comment: No I am looking at the paths in Linux, there are quite a few files in the /etc directory, but no folder called 'group'

Comment: I have Ambari as well, but the commands we are discussing above were typed into Linux.

Comment: go to ambari console and under HDFS -> Configs -> Advanced -> core-site.xml

Comment: When I try to access hdfs on Ambari, it says permission denied: 'org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=admin, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/user/hdfs":hdfs:hdfs:drwx------'. When I try to change the permissions via Ambari it says 'failed to modify' and the error is 'Can't chmod '/user/hdfs''

Comment: Hi Nimal, do you have any further ideas?

Comment: I have found my cote-site.xml, which entries do you want from it? It is too large to paste it all here.